# How do I filter using user selected value with Angular Material Select?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a dropdown filter in angular material. Here is the array for my dropdown options

```
 public intensities = ['All',1,2,3,4,5]
```

Here is the html for the mat-select field.

```
    <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select placeholder="Choose Intensity" [(ngModel)]="selectedIntensity" (selectionChange)="onIntensityChange()">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let intensity of intensities" [value]="intensity">
                            {{intensity}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
     </mat-form-field>

 <div class="flex-wrap" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;">Show Shoppers With: </span>
                <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hiddenWithoutPhone" (change)="filterVisibleShoppers()">Phone
                <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hiddenWithoutEmail" (change)="filterVisibleShoppers()">Email
                <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hiddenWithoutAddress" (change)="filterVisibleShoppers()">Address
                <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hiddenWithoutTradeIn" (change)="filterVisibleShoppers()">Trade In
            </div>
```

I am trying to write a function 'onIntensityChange()' that displays the correct choices based on the user selection. I also have a filter that works with a checkbox. I'd like to be able to filter based on both selections(dropdown and checkbox) Here is the typescript file.

```
   @Component({
        templateUrl: 'daily-active-shopper.screen.html',
    })

    export class DailyActiveShoppersScreen {

        public selectedDate: Date;
        public maxDate: Date = new Date();
        public count = 0;
        public customers;
        public loading: boolean;

        public hiddenWithoutEmail: boolean;
        public hiddenWithoutPhone: boolean;
        public hiddenWithoutAddress: boolean;
        public hiddenWithoutTradeIn: boolean;

        _dealerId: number;

        activeShopperDay: DailyActiveShopperDay;
        visibleActiveShoppers: DailyActiveShopper[];

        shopperDetailsVisible = true;
        shopperErrorMessage: string;

        public intensities = ['All',1,2,3,4,5]
        public selectedIntensity: any; 

 filterVisibleShoppers() {
        let shoppers = this.activeShopperDay.shoppers;
        if (this.hiddenWithoutAddress) {
            shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                return shopper.state !== null;
            });
        }
        if (this.hiddenWithoutPhone) {
            shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                return shopper.phone !== null;
            });
        }
        if (this.hiddenWithoutEmail) {
            shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                return shopper.email !== null;
            });
        }
        if (this.hiddenWithoutTradeIn) {
            shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                return shopper.currentVehicle;
            });
        }
        this.visibleActiveShoppers = shoppers;
    }

    onIntensityChange() {
        console.log(this.selectedIntensity);
        let shoppers = this.activeShopperDay.shoppers;
            if(this.selectedIntensity === 'All') {
                shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                    return this.visibleActiveShoppers = shoppers;
                })
            }
            if(this.selectedIntensity === 1) {
               shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                    return shopper.intensity === this.selectedIntensity
                })
            }
            if(this.selectedIntensity === 2) {
                shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                    return shopper.intensity === this.selectedIntensity
                })
}
            if(this.selectedIntensity === 3) {
                shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                    return shopper.intensity === this.selectedIntensity
                })
            }
            if(this.selectedIntensity === 4) {
                shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                    return shopper.intensity === this.selectedIntensity
                })
            }
            if(this.selectedIntensity === 5) {
                shoppers = shoppers.filter((shopper) => {
                    return shopper.intensity === this.selectedIntensity
                })
            }

            if(this.visibleActiveShoppers.length < 1) {
                console.log("None found for this intensity")
            }
            this.visibleActiveShoppers = shoppers;
    }
```

I'm looking for a proper way to implement this. Basically allowing the user to filter based on intensity and the four radio buttons.

Comment: Could you please add the rest of your TS part ?

Comment: Do you need the entire file? I am also wanting to filter using radio buttons as well.

Comment: There is some undefined -for me at least- variables, such as `activeShopperDay`, `visibleActiveShoppers`.. so yes if you want !

Comment: Does this help. I've added more of the TS file.

Comment: Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-6-3mxwvd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for your case , try to add there your missed models `DailyActiveShopperDay` and `DailyActiveShopper`.

Comment: This looks like the same thing I already have.

Comment: no missed  DailyActiveShopperDay and DailyActiveShopper @LDB